# SaaS in Ruby on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, saas

I want to build a RoR web application in SaaS architecture. Should I have a single database for every clients or multiple databases for each client. And also I wonder that each client should use the own separated application on sub domain or not. Although it depends on business logic but I want to learn how I can choose the correct way and what the best practice is.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct answer here.  The first solution would be to have each client completely independent: their own application space and database.

However, you may want to design a framework which is common to all clients, and just change the branding for each client.  The downside of this is the effort you need to keep them separated - for instance cross-contamination and security.